# React formik partialy update initial values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

In my react component I have these two initial values

```
 const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 85,
  });
```

And I have a text field to change the values for the name field. And I have a button to change the age field.

If I type name as 'Jerry' and press that button to update the age It will update the age to 75 and reset the name 'Jerry' to 'Tom' again.

[This is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-re-render-initialvalues-forked-f7pg5)

Type Jerry in the text box and hit the button to see that it changes to the "Tom"

How do I fix this?

Anyhelp!
Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: The name is reset to 'Tom' again because of line 26: `setInitialValues({ ...initialValues, age: 75 });`. The `initialValues` is `{ name: 'Tom', age: 85 }`, so you're using the spread(`...`) operator to spread the `initialValues`, overwriting only the `age` property, whilst the `name` property stays as 'Tom'.

Comment: @Kapobajza How can I fix this?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve? You want to submit the form and the value of the input field should be the same as the one you submitted?

Comment: I have initial values, whiling the user entering some fields I want to update some of the initial values using an API call. @Kapobajza

Comment: Try this: just change the line 26 from `setInitialValues({ ...initialValues, age: 75 });` to: `setInitialValues({ name: /* get the value of the name text field */, age: 75 });`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reset form values like that to initial values.

What you need to do is to use method `resetForm()` from Formik form ref.

You provide only once what are initial values, and reset when ever you need to.

I forked your codesanbox and modified code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-re-render-initialvalues-forked-i84sy

Here are parts of the code related to what you need to do

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
...

const Page = () => {
  const formikRef = useRef();

  const setValues = () => {
    console.log("hh");
    setInitialValues({ ...initialValues, age: 75 });
    formikRef.current.resetForm();
  };
  ...
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setValues}>API Call</button>

      <Formik
        ref={(ref) => {
          formikRef.current = ref;
        }}
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={submit}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        enableReinitialize
      >
        ...
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**EDIT**
I added one more part that covers modifying initial values. First you need to set `initialValues` and than do `formikRef.current.resetForm()`.

**NOTE**

If you upgrade Formik to `2.x.x` `ref` is changed to `innerRef`:

```js
<Formik
  innerRef={(ref) => {
    formikRef.current = ref;
  }}
></Formik>;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, I have initial values, whiling the user entering some fields I want to update some of the initial values using an API call. Is there a way to do so.

Comment: Ah ok. I modified Codesanbox. Take a look. I will modify my answer as well